# retrieve data from multiple tables and store them in one table confronted the duplicates

Tags: sql-server, database, data-warehouse

I'm working on some critical data retrieving report tasks and find some difficulties to
proceed. Basically, it's belonging to medical area and the whole data is distributed in
several tables and I can't change the architecture of database tables design. In order to
finish my report, I need the following steps:

```
1- divide the whole report to several parts, for each parts retrieve data by using
several joins. (like for part A can be retrieved by this:
select a1.field1, a2.field2 from a1 left join a2 on a1.fieldA= a2.fieldA ) then I can
got all the data from part A.

2- the same things happened for part B
select b1.field1, b2.field2 from b1 left join b2 on b1.fieldB= b2.fieldB, then I also
get all the data from part B.

3- same case for part C, part D.....and so on.
```

The reason I divide them is that for each part I need to have more than 8 joins (medical data is always complex) so I can't finish all of them within a single join (with more than 50 joins which is impossible to finish...)

After that, I run my Spring Batch program to insert all the data from part A and data from part b, part c.. into one table as my final report table. The problem is not every part will have same number of rows which means part A may return 10 rows while part b may return 20 rows. Since the time condition for each part is the same (1 day) and can't be changed so just wondering how can I store all these different part of data into one table with minimum overhead. I don't want to have to many duplicates, thanks for the great help.

Lei

Comment: It isn't clear what your actual problem is: the process you've described might be a good one for your situation. If you're asking if the general approach is efficient then the answer is "it depends on your data volume, schema complexity etc." and I don't think anyone else can answer it. If you're asking "how do I make this code run faster" then you need to provide some sample code and execution plans. One obvious comment would be to bypass Spring and use pure SQL code if possible, but it isn't clear from your question exactly what language your code is in anyway.

Comment: Sorry, my questio is about how to integrate my divided results from part A, part B... and so on into one table like table_report. The difficulty is I need to combine these results back into one row while each parts may return different number of rows. Please help me solve this, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you using? The question is quite broad and you need to be specific... if you get data of different granularity back from each 'part', then you need to figure out how to summarize it to the appropriate granularity (or allocate it down..)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like what you need are joins over the "data from part A", "data from part B" & "data from part C". Lets call them da, db & dc.
It's perfectly alright that num rows in da/b/c are different. But as you're trying to put them all in a single table at the end, obviously there is some relation between them. Without better description of that relation it's not possible to provide a more concrete answer. So I'll just write my thoughts, which you might already know, but anyway...

Simplest way is to join results from your 3 [inner] queries in a higher level [outer] query.

```
select j.x, j.y, j.z
from (
   ' da join db join dc
) j;
```

If this is not possible (due to way too many joins as you said) then try one of these:

1. Create 3 separate [materialized views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) (one each for da, db & dc) and perform the join these views. Materialized is optional (i.e. you can use the "normal" views too), but it should improve the performance greatly if available in your DB.
2. First run queries for da/b/c, fetch the data and put this data in intermediate tables. Run a join on those tables.

PS: If you want to run reports (many/frequent/large size) on some data then that data should be designed appropriately, else you'll run into heap of trouble in future.

If you want something more concrete, please post the relationship between da/b/c.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The relation between each data part can be linked by clinic number--a kind of unique identification. The outter join is not possible because of too many joins already done in each data part. I will try the materialized views first and see the performance. Thank you.